# Range operators in Ruby similar to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, range, date-range

Is there a Ruby gem that enables Range calculations similar to what [PostgreSQL does](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE)? Especially the time-related range functions?

Answer (score 0):

There's [`Range#cover?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) to test if an object is between the begin and end of the range.

Ruby's equivalent to `'[2011-01-01,2011-03-01)'::tsrange @> '2011-01-10'::timestamp` is:

```
(Date.new(2011,01,01)..Date.new(2011,03,01)).cover? Date.new(2011,01,10)
# => true
```

It tests `Date.new(2011,01,01) <= Date.new(2011,01,10) <= Date.new(2011,03,01)`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you are trying to accomplish it's hard to answer this question, but you may want to check out the CoreExtensions module of the ActiveSupport gem: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html

Install ActiveSupport with `gem install activesupport` or add it to your Gemfile.

With ActiveSupport you can do things like this:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

10.days.from_now #=> 2013-06-08 08:37:34 -0400
DateTime.now.beginning_of_year #=> Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 -0400
1.megabyte #=> 1048576
(1..10).step(2) #=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
(1..10).overlaps?(0..7) #=> true
Date.current.next_month #=> Sat, 29 Jun 2013
Date.current.prev_week(:friday) #=> Fri, 24 May 2013
```

I hope this helps.